# collapse a collapsiblePanel by Javascript

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I would like to know how to collapse a collapsiblePanel (richfaces 4) by Javascript ?

I was using SimpleTogglePanel (richfaces 3) with SimpleTogglePanelManager.toggleOnClien to do this. Is there any alternative similar manager for collapsiblePanel  in richfaces 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to collapse the panel:

```
// For collapsiblePanel 'false' is collapsed item.
RichFaces.$(panelClientId).switchToItem('false');
```

or with EL:

```
#{rich:component('panelId')}.switchToItem('false');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no central controller anyomore, the panel itself has a `switchPanel` method (see the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-richcollapsiblePanel-JavaScript_API)).

You can either call it by pure JS

```
RichFaces.$('form:panel').switchPanel();
```

or using EL

```
#{rich:component('panel')}.switchPanel();
```

Comment: I haven't check this solution which you have suggested yet, but I need to open or close intentionally not just toggling. Andrey's solution is working fine for my purpose.